# Difference-in-Difference with temporary event

Tags: statistical-significance, econometrics, categorical-encoding, difference-in-difference

I am running a Diff-in-Diff analysis about the triggering of a policy that once triggered bans a certain action for 6 months.

I have run the analysis considering only pre and post period, including in the post-period also the observations that are after the 6-month period, that is, when the ban was actually released.

Now I want to run a robustness check and I want to consider the fact that after the 6-month period the ban is gone.

**How can I do this?**

I thought I could simply change my EVENT vector, which had a dummy equal $0$ for pre-treatment and $1$ for post-treatment. Could I just change this and do:
$0$ for pre-treatment, $1$ for post-treatment, $0$ for released-treatment.

It seems wrong to me. isn't it? should I then change also the treatment vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice depends on whether you expect a lingering effect in the released-from-treatment period. This expectation can come from theory or domain expertise.

If that is sensible in your setting, then you should have two separate post dummies and two treated-post interactions. The two interaction coefficients will allow the effect to vary in the two post-treatment regimes.

The coding scheme you propose would be suitable if you expect the effect to go away immediately (like a light switch being turned off).

Comment: Yeah I expect lingering effects. so you mean to have an event dummy vector = 1 for the dates after the event and 0 for dates before the event. Then, create another event dummy vector = 1 for all dates before the release and 0 after the release. Then, multiply the treatment vector for both event vectors, generating two treatment*event vectors. Then, run everything in one regression. is that right? if that's the case, is this a robustness check? it looks more like an original regression: the main regression that I should run and that should be later tested by another different robustness check.

Comment: If you have monthly data, I would use post_treatment dummy (with pattern ...0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,...) and post_release dummy (...0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,...) for pre, during, and post months. If you expect a lingering effect, then this would be your main specification and not a robustness check. A potential robustness check would use time dummies and their interactions with treated instead of post dummies. This would add even more flexibility: a separate effect for every period. This could let you test parallel trends in the pre-period, and allow the treatment effect to vary over time.

Comment: @Mining To complement the answer above, see the last equation in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/480954/diff-in-diff-time-varying-treatment). A second interaction is warranted if you suspect a lingering policy effect.

Comment: @dimitriy to make sure i understood. 

I do a post treatment dummy in which 0 is pre treatment, 1 is during treatment, and 0 is after release. then I do a post release dummy in which 0 is pre treatment, 0 is during treatment, and 1 is after release. Then I multiply the treatment (1 for treated and 0 for control) for the vectors explained above and I get 2 main diff in diff coefficients: one for the during treatment and one for the after release. right?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: thanks a lot @dimitriy