# Multiple treatment dynamic diff-in-diff

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have a question regarding the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504144/difference-in-differences-dynamic-treatment-group-timing). In @Thomas Bilach answer, he gives the following example, which I have edited a bit more to add my own hypothetical examples:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
item  & day   & D_{it} & D_{it}^{-3} & D_{it}^{-2} & D_{it}^{-1} & D_{it}^{0} & D_{it}^{+1} & D_{it}^{+2} & D_{it}^{+3} \\
\hline
1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 2     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 3     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 4     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 5     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 6     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 7     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
1     & 8     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\ \hline
2     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
2     & 2     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
2     & 3     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
2     & 4     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0 \\
2     & 5     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0 \\
2     & 6     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 (?) \\
2     & 7     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
2     & 8     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\ \hline
3     & 1     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
3     & 2     & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
3     & 3     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
3     & 4     & 1     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
3     & 5     & 1     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0 \\
3     & 6     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 0 (?) & 0 \\
3     & 7     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) \\
3     & 8     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1 (?) & 0     & 0 \\ \hline
4     & 1     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 2     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 3     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 4     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 5     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 6     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 7     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
4     & 8     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\ \hline
5     & 1     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\ 
5     & 2     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 3     & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 4     & 0     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 5     & 0     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 6     & 0     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 7     & 0     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
5     & 8     & 0     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\end{array}
$$

In particular, item 4 is **always** treated (before day 1 even begins). Item 5 is already treated (before day 1 begins) but switches off from day 4 onwards.

My objective is to estimate a dynamic version of the above difference in difference in the spirit of @Thomas Bilach answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523032/testing-parallel-trends-in-staggered-difference-in-differences). However, I am having trouble with this in the context where treatment switches on and off. It is easy in the classical difference in difference where treatment stays on, but I am unsure how to manually create the dynamic dummy variables in the above example.

To get started, $D_{it}^{-3}$ denotes the treatment effect 3 days before the treatment event day. The other dummies are defined similarly. I've tried my best to fill in the values, but anything with a $(?)$ next to it, I am unsure whether I filled in the correct value. Take, for example, item 2 on day 6, if treatment on day 3 was permanent, then clearly $D_{it}^{+3}=1$, but because item 2 **switches** off on day 6, then should $D_{it}^{+3}$ be set to $0$? Similarly, item 3 causes me a lot of confusion, since it enters treatment on day 4, switches off on day 6, but enters treatment again on day 7. How do I define the dynamic dummies then?

Items 4 and 5, I have no idea how to set the dummies.

Comment: Do you have a lot of units where they switch back and forth between the treatment and control condition?

Comment: Yes, quite a lot of observations switch back and forth...